# Excel Calculations using TIME()

Tags: microsoft-excel

I frequently use Excel to calculate the decimal time spent working on something rounded up to the nearest 1/10 of an hour.

For example:
A1 is the start time

B1 is the end time

C1 is the total time rounded up to the nearest 1/10 of an hour

```
A1:13:53   B1:14:19   C1:0.5
```

I calculate this using:

```
=ROUNDUP((((B1-A1)*1440)/60),1)
```

It gets tedious always having to enter the colon separator between the hour and the minutes when I enter the start and end times, so I would like to use only the number keypad to enter the times:

```
A1:13  B1:53  C1:14  D1:19  E1:0.5
```

I've tried the following, but it does not work:

```
=ROUNDUP(((((TIME(C1,D1,0)-TIME(A1,B1,0))*1440)/60),1)
```

How can I accomplish my goal of entering times to be calculated without having to use the colon separator?

Comment: looks like you have 1 too many open parentheses...

Comment: The most easiest is to convert Decimal numbers into TIME is divide it by 24 & apply an appropriate Cell Format for TIME best suitable is HH:MM AM/PM ,,,  Military time can be converted into Standard Time also,,, another is using VBA macro ,,, if you are comfortable with it then please edit your post & add this as well VBA TAG !

Comment: Actually, the formual `=ROUNDUP(((((TIME(C1,D1,0)-TIME(A1,B1,0))*1440)/60),1)` could be `=ROUNDUP(((TIME(C1,D1,0)-TIME(A1,B1,0))*1440/60),1)`. The [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyL7F.png) on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to entering times without having to use the colon separator, you may format the cells as Custom "##":"##".
[image]

Then you may use this formula like `=ROUNDUP(((TIME(LEFT(B5,2),RIGHT(B5,2),0)-TIME(LEFT(A5,2),RIGHT(A5,2),0))*1440/60),1)`.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you.